# Disambiguate the [carbon] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-disambiguation

It seems that, through a long history of neglect, the [carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carbon) tag has acquired not two, but *three* different meanings:

- [A set of Apple APIs used during the transition from Mac OS 9 to OS X](https://web.archive.org/web/20121012135554/https://developer.apple.com/carbon/)
- [A PHP date/time library](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)
- [One of the components of the Graphite data collection/graphing system](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon)

The tag wiki suggests that the first meaning is correct. (Indeed, I believe the tag wiki was written before either of the other projects existed!) However, the contents of the tag disagree; most of the recent questions are about the PHP library, with a substantial minority being about the Graphite component.

How should this be handled?

Comment: Bi [carbon] ate?

Comment: for the php library i'd use nesbot-carbon

Comment: @Tschallacka I'd dare say that "nesbot" is not particularly meaningful. However, [tag:php-carbon] already exists and has 272 questions so far.

Comment: It's also a [PowerShell module](http://get-carbon.org/). Not sure if it's being confused for that, though.

Comment: See also now https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419541/time-to-free-carbon-from-php?cb=1

Answer (score 13):

I say this as a PHP developer myself - PHP devs are *not the best at reading*.  But, I'll save my rants for another place.

It would appear that many askers are ignoring, or unable to read, the tag descriptions.  This is despite the fact that `[php-carbon]` is the third option to show up when I start typing 'carbon' in the Tags field:

[image: 'carbon' tagging options]

If we look at the creation dates in the wiki history:

### [[carbon]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/carbon)

Carbon is Apple's previous application-development framework for Mac OS X, which existed primarily for applications that needed to remain compatible with the Classic Mac OS. Much of it is now deprecated and unavailable to 64-bit applications as of Mac OS X 10.6.

**created Aug 5 '10 at 9:31**

### [[php-carbon]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon)

Carbon is a library written in PHP that extends the native DateTime class.

**created Feb 6 '14 at 15:54**

It would appear that indeed, the `[carbon]` tag (for OSX's framework) pre-dates the tag for the PHP library by nearly 4 years!

Furthermore, it would appear that [[graphite]](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon) in terms of both its tag creation date and the creation of its repo on [Github](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/graphs/contributors), is also older than [[php-carbon]](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/graphs/contributors).

So, it looks like PHP's Carbon library is the new kid on the block.

There are a few solutions:

#### Solution 1

**Status quo.** Create a new tag for the Graphite questions (either `[graphite-carbon]` or `[carbon-graphite]`), and clean up the miscategorized `[carbon]` questions.  Note that this will require regular maintenance to edit mistagged questions.

It's possible that renaming `[php-carbon]` to `[carbon-php]` will make it more obvious to the question-askers, when they're typing up their ill-conceived questions at 4am and looking through blurry eyeballs at the suggestions popup.

#### Solution 2

**Go with the flow.**  Us PHP developers are convinced that the world revolves around us.  Hand over `[carbon]` to the PHP library, OSX can move its questions to `[osx-carbon]` or `[apple-carbon]`, and Python people can go with `[graphite-carbon]`.  After all, the Apple library is largely deprecated, and only [32 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carbon+graphite) have *both* the `[carbon]` and `[graphite]` tags.

#### Solution 3

[**Burninate!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info)  Also, known as "this is why we can't have nice things."  We can decide that `carbon` is simply too ambiguous for *any* question, and instead have `[php-carbon]`, `[osx-carbon]`, and `[graphite-carbon]` (or something along those lines).

Comment: FWIW: I didn't just mean that [tag:carbon] is older than [tag:php-carbon]; I meant that [tag:carbon] is older than the Carbon PHP library itself! (And surely Solution 3 should be "Carbonize"? :D)

Comment: Or, we could freeze it...in carbonite!

Comment: definitely option 3.  As long as the ambiguous tag is around users of the other two libraries will tag it by mistake.  Maybe blacklist it too, to keep it from coming back.

Comment: FWIW, if we established a new tag for the Apple library, a more appropriate name would be [tag:apple-carbon] -- the library was available for both Mac OS X and for Classic Mac OS (Mac OS 8.6 and 9). Or perhaps [tag:carbonlib], which is what the library file was called.

Comment: In the last week or so, I've cleaned up the tag [tag:esql] which had three separate meanings: [tag:embedded-sql], [tag:entity-sql] and [tag:extended-sql].  When I last looked, there were two questions with the original [tag:esql] because I couldn't work out whether they're really [tag:entity-sql] or [tag:extended-sql] — and leaving them so tagged means that the [tag:esql] wiki survives and points the way to the correct tags.  This is entirely analogous to the [tag:carbon] problem.  Solution 3 is good, but perhaps keep [tag:carbon] around to disambiguate the three contexts.

Comment: Or Solution 4: Annoy them into submission! Answer each question tagged this way as if it were an Apple Carbon question, and write an answer explaining how to do whatever they're asking for using `WaitNextEvent()` or `TESetStyleHandle()` or `FSGetCatalogInfoBulk()` until they get the hint and knock it off. ;-)

Comment: Went with solution 3... all have their own tags

Answer (score 2):

So I've cleaned this up now (I didn't go through it with a fine tooth comb, I just checked for common tags).

- Anything with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) is now under [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon)
- Created the [graphite-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphite-carbon) tag and retagged all [graphite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphite) to it
- Retagged anything about [wso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2) to [wso2carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2carbon) (tag already existed)
- The remaining 528 questions all seem related to [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx)

I also edited the excerpt to make it abundantly clear it's for OSX, but I don't hold out much hope for that. People don't read. I actually found several questions tagged both [carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carbon) and the correct tag.