# Rename [carbon] to [macos-carbon] and synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Related to [Disambiguate the [carbon] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349864/disambiguate-the-carbon-tag)

There is a continuing problem with people using this tag to refer to any project with "carbon" in its name. I cleaned it up a while back (the most common misuse is [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) questions, which are related to [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon)). To be clear, I've continued to clean this tag out periodically. Rather than continue to cross my fingers and hope for the best, I'm suggesting we do the following

1. Create the [macos-carbon] tag
2. Synonym [carbon] to [macos-carbon]

This makes the difference fairly explicit and easy to spot. It's far less likely people will mistag things as [macos-carbon]

Comment: Just the job for a diamond mod, then:)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not completely comfortable with this. Carbon is not really an OS X API. It's actually an API for the classic Mac OS, and OS X just included support for it to ease portability to the then-new system. Maybe we should call the tag [macos-carbon]? (Because everything old is new again: "Mac OS" vs. "macOS".)

Comment: @CodyGray I'd be fine with that as well. [carbon] is just too ambiguous to leave standing

Comment: This appears to be a recurring issue. IMO, the issue is that [[tag:carbon]] is too ambiguous. Given it's current primary usage, it should be renamed to something Apple/Mac specific, but that tag should not be synonymed with [carbon]. [carbon] should just not exist. If the Apple usage of the term was far more prevalent than any other use, then a synonym would be reasonable, but the [[tag:php-carbon]] tag has basically the same number of questions. There is a significant difference in volume of questions wrt.  [[tag:graphite-carbon]], or any other use of "carbon", just not vs. PHP.