# Too much [carbon] is bad for the environment

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process, blocklist-request, synonym-removal-request

It seems like [carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carbon) was [made a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php-carbon/synonyms) of [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon) in the scope of [this MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349864/disambiguate-the-carbon-tag) (which was probably fine at that point) (or it was probably synonymized later).

However, as [there seems to be a new programming language called Carbon](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang), this is confusing.

If people want to ask a question about the Carbon programming language and see a [carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carbon) tag, they will probably use it without looking.

Since

> [PHP devs are *not the best at reading*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349964/10871900)

I suggest altogether removing the [carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carbon) tag (and maybe blacklisting it as there is a high chance that someone will recreate it in the future) and creating a new tag called [carbon-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carbon-lang) (or similar) for the programming language called Carbon.

Comment: Adding carbon ... not sure if that is environmental sustainable ...

Comment: @rene That's another reason to remove it.

Comment: *"PHP devs are not the best at reading"* if only this was true for just PHP devs. Unfortunately, it's more accurate to say "[so] users are not the best at reading". Disambiguation and then black listing does seem to be the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: In the mean time, I would suggest retagging anything incorrectly tagged as [[tag:php-carbon]] to [[tag:carbon-lang]] (or other correct tag). That does seem to be the better name, as it's also the name of the [repo](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang)

Comment: @Larnu I only found one such question and I'd say that specific question is not worth anything else than closing.

Comment: If there's only 1 question, and it's not on topic, I feel like this question loses credibility, @dan1st . I, and I presume others, would infer that there has been a problem with Carbon (language) developers tagging [[tag:php-carbon]].

Comment: @Larnu Currently, there is only that one question but I wanted to address this soon enough so we can easily fix it (The language Carbon is new) without manually reviewing lots of questions.

Comment: Suggest changing title to "Let's sequester [carbon]".

Comment: Lots of good pun opportunities here... burnination, [carbon] capture, [carbon] release, reduce our [carbon] footprint...

Comment: Carbon burnination makes Meta Posts Hot.  Meta Warming is not a hoax.

Comment: CMs: the status-review is to have [tag:carbon] blacklisted; as outlined in the question, it's too ambiguous to risk having it occur as a full tag, and the introduction of Google Carbon makes the synonym bad. I haven't removed the synonym yet to avoid any extra cleanup work in the meanwhile, though feel free to do that if that's necessary to blacklist. Otherwise, I'll remove the synonym afterwards.

Comment: As for creating [tag:carbon-lang], as is tradition, we need an actual question (read: posting placeholder questions to initialize the tag isn't okay, so let's skip that please kthx in advancing) to apply the tag to. [carbon-lang] is consistent with a number of other languages where the name of the language itself is ambiguous. as a bonus, carbon-lang is also consistent with [their GH](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang), so it's about as close as we get to an official alternate name.

Comment: Should we make SO less organic?

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine someone asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191274/slices-vs-arrays-in-carbon-language) and created [tag:google-carbon] and [tag:carbon-language]. Maybe the first tag should be deleted and the other renamed.

Comment: @jps removed both, made [carbon-lang], and made both of the two synonym for [carbon-lang]. Should solve the problem for the immediate future. Barring new, creative names for the language showing up as tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reviewed the request and got Yaakov to block the tag. Using it should now throw the error:

> The 'carbon' tag is not allowed.
>
> Please use a more specific tag to describe the subject of your question, such as [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon) or [graphite-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphite-carbon).

[image: Red text on a black background showing the error message text described in the quote above.]

As a note, to get the error to come up, I had to remove the synonym to [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon), so that's been done, which I think was expected.

Comment: The [tag:carbon-lang] now exists with a few questions. Would it be possible/reasonable to include this in the message? It seems likely that someone looking to ask a question about Carbon may try to use the carbon tag.

Answer (score 7):

Carbon has [been a continual problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356485/rename-carbon-to-macos-carbon-and-synonym), actually. This makes project #4 named Carbon, which gets to join

- [macos-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-carbon)
- [graphite-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphite-carbon)
- [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon)

Of those three, the most common use is [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon), which is extensively used by [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) (PHP framework). Hence why I added the synonym instead of letting the problem fester again (someone had re-created it and it had all sorts of misuse).

This is, honestly, a by-product of [how bad the tagging system is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387405/2370483) (it's not just a matter of reading, when a common way to access SO gives you nothing to read). I tend to agree with Zoe, that in a sane world we would block [carbon] as being too generic, but I also know that, given how the current system works, it's not going to solve anything. Tag search is too simple and users will tag it based on whatever they see. I had to admit defeat a while back on [linux-disk-free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-disk-free), and repoint the synonym [df] to [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) for that reason (no, they weren't even reading which tag they were adding).

I don't think blocking [carbon] will help a lot here (not many users misusing the tag have the create tags privilege, which is the only way you'd see the block message). It synonyms to the PHP tag due to popularity. I think this is the best we can get, currently. If the tagging UX (especially mobile) gets some improvements, I'd say a revisit is in order.