# I want to seed Stack Overflow with questions about my product/project. What do I need to know?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions, tag-seeding

I run a project or business that involves coding and I'd like for people to be able to find information about this on Stack Overflow. What do I need to know about doing this? Is this allowed?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

> **Moderator note:** This question is for the purpose of building a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry

Comment: Good documentation heads off questions on both SO and issue trackers.  For complex topics, I do video tutorials and embed that into the documentation.  Both of those options are time investments and part of the software development lifecycle.  Treating every open issue where someone asks a question as a possible documentation problem will result in better documentation, which prevents other people from asking the same question later.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This issue reoccurs on a frequent basis on Stack Overflow. If you want to seed (or just answer) questions about your project, be aware of the following

### Can I support my product here?

Generally the answer is "Yes", but [we do have a page with guidelines for product support](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). The TL;DR here is

> Stack Overflow can *help* support your product but it can't be the *only* support. There are issues that only you can address; if you send your users to Stack Overflow for support that only you can offer, they'll just get frustrated.

Remember, [Stack Overflow is not a substitute for customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745). The general breakdown of that page is that we try to help your users use your software. We don't cover things like bugs in your software, service outages, company policies, etc.

### Tagging

It's generally best to create a tag for your project if there are *multiple* questions related to your project. [There are community guidelines for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions). Keep the tag name as short as possible and avoid using only acronyms (acronym meanings can change). If the same name tag exists, please add some specificity to the tag. For instance, there are [many projects named Carbon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419541), so we force specificity by adding prefixes like [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon) (where PHP is a language). In some cases, we add the name of the company first (like [microsoft-graph-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-graph-api))

### Questions must be on-topic

A common mistake here is attempting to synthetically create postings about your product. Some examples of this would be

- Explaining about the various levels of service you have
- Contrasting different types of software you have
- Anything that does not fit into our Q&A format (i.e. the section below of documentation)

Here's a real example of just such an off-topic seed question

> When using [software library], what is the recommended way to structure the code? Is there a certain file directory structure or naming convention required?

The community is not receptive to anything that is not a real, answerable question. Look at other similar questions, or [read the help center on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first.

### Don't recreate your documentation on Stack Overflow

Seriously, we've been there, done that, and [it did not go well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation). The mistake here is in trying to shoehorn your documentation into a Q&A format. **Don't do that.**

Stack Overflow is here to help people with their *coding problems*. Simple questions can be asked (i.e. "How do I do this in X?"), but they tend to be received poorly for not demonstrating a **practical** problem that one would expect to encounter in the real world. If the purpose of your question is solely so you can answer it with your documentation, it's very likely to be off-topic.

Also remember that answers that consist mostly (or entirely) of pasted documentation ([cited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) or not), are not allowed.

### Limit your promotion

Talking about your product/project too much is [considered spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

> **Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much.** Folks will read your answers for their ability to solve a specific problem; if you're good at doing that, then they'll find themselves more interested in who you are and what you're working on. If you respond only to questions where the answer can be something you're selling, they'll assume you're just here to sell.

These rules apply to both free and paid solutions. Moreover, **you must disclose when you are talking about your product/project**.

Posting about your project too much may lead to the removal of many or all of your posts.

### Answer seeding

Answer seeding is when a project author/member goes around looking for questions that could be solved with their project. The rules here are

1. Answers using your product or project must disclose your involvement in said project
2. You must **demonstrate how to solve the problem with your project**. In other words, show us code using your project that answers the question at hand. Simply linking to the project or library is [not acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/)
3. Don't post multiple answers on similar questions. [We have a rule about that one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). If the same answer applies to multiple questions, please answer one and flag the others as duplicate questions.
4. Don't answer just to point to your support structure (i.e. "Email us at..." or "Please file a bug report at..."). You can do that in comments.
5. Don't throw links to your project into everything. It looks promotional (as mentioned above). This will get all your posts with links deleted, and a diamond moderator will likely message you to tell you to knock it off.

### Don't get your coworkers to vote on your posts

This is the largest single problem we run into with seeding: voting rings. There are two problems in this wheelhouse

1. Voting for coworkers
2. Answering coworkers' questions

If you're going to post something of a seeding nature, answer your own question. There is nothing wrong with this (and you even get a handy checkbox to do it when asking). The problem with answering a coworker's question is that if they accept your answer, you gain reputation (which is a type of voting fraud).

When you get your coworkers involved with voting, users and moderators will notice the unusual voting pattern. From the standard targeted voting message

> We recently noticed a substantial number of votes on your account to or from specific users. While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts and downvote bad ones, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the *post*, **not the person who wrote it.** Please refrain from targeting specific users when voting.

And from [the voting page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

> **When should I not vote up?**
>
> - Repeatedly upvoting posts created by people you know because you know them – often friends, family, or coworkers.

Answer your own questions, and let the community decide if the posts you've made are useful. Do not let your coworkers or friends vote on your posts.