# Why wasn't this spam post deleted even after getting a helpful flag?

Tags: support, spam, helpful-flags

Last week, I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72917830/5211833) as spam, along with its answer. The reason for that being that all 16 answers of that user pointed to the library they wrote and most answers were unattributed up to the moment someone left a comment that they should do so. Thus, after discussion in the SOCVR I flagged the lot as spam, all of which were accepted:

[Screenshot of a subset of my flagged posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKcH2.png)

What I don't get, is why my flag on the initial post got marked "Helpful - This is a poor spam flag. In isolation, this post doesn’t look like spam *at all*". Whilst I agree that it doesn't appear to be spam on the surface, given that I, and others in the SOCVR, flagged around 18 posts linking to this domain as spam this should be deleted as being a spam seed + spam answer in my opinion.

Why was the flag marked helpful, but the post left alone? I raised a custom flag on one of their posts detailing the issue, which was also marked helpful. Should I have custom flagged this one as well?

Comment: Their answer on that post does have a disclaimer at the end that they are the developer of that package.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, which I've mentioned in the OP. The problem here, is that they didn't do this once, but that I've flagged 16 answers of theirs. Thus, attributed or not, all they used their answering privileges for was to promote their own toolbox. Also, the red flag on this specific answer did get marked helpful.

Comment: From what I understand spam and excessive promotion are treated a bit differently, I am guessing that the mod felt that the Q&A pair might be useful and did meet the [criteria described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow/260641#260641) so they left that Q&A pair. The user has probably received a warning from the moderators as well so any future actions from their end will invite more repercussions.

Comment: *"Why was the flag marked helpful, but the post left alone?"* - Because it is handled by human beings who can judge case by case :) I know that almost everything is automated so you start to expect the cold, neutral and often harsh decisions of an algorithm, but that doesn't make this situation strange :) We can only wait for the mod who handled the flag to explain what they were thinking.

Comment: Marking a flag “helpful” is not necessarily a sign that the flag intent will be acted upon. It’s simply that the intention was not misguided and the flag valid. The mod can anyway in further research disagree or come to their own conclusions, but avoid marking the flag “declined”, because it was nonetheless a “good” flag, that could have gone either way.

Comment: 16 answers? I only see one :-)

Comment: @Dominique the rest are deleted by the moderators.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I marked your flag helpful because it was. The question is what we call [seeding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421604/i-want-to-seed-stack-overflow-with-questions-about-my-product-project-what-do-i). It was an acceptable flag, as the user was in violation of the guidelines surrounding [excessive self-promotion](/help/promotion), especially this part:

> Post good, relevant answers, and if **some (but not all)** happen to be about your product or website, that's okay.

It was not a particularly *good* flag because the post wasn't evil spam, and as a Q&A about their own product it was surprisingly well crafted. I thought the OP had made a real effort to provide useful content: they managed to create a reasonably on-topic question, the answer is self-contained, it included disclosure of affiliation from the get go, and it wasn't a random recommendation to an existing unrelated question.

Critically, the OP had already faced discipline afterwards, including deletion of all their other questions and answers by three other moderators — who also did not delete that post.

All things considered, deleting that Q&A *now* seemed to me an unnecessary punishment.

In general, a flag is marked helpful when it is, quite literally, helpful. It doesn't automatically imply that the post will always
be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Stand-alone this'd be my thoughts exactly. On-topic, well attributed and -written self-promotion. What I don't get, though, is that this can remain on site with all their other answers being spam-deleted. That makes it sound as if a single good post with promotional intent amidst a larger number of true spam posts is actually OK. The sole purpose of this account (apart from 2 questions posted years ago) appears to be to promote (not even support up to now) this library.

Comment: Sometimes we do leave *only* one post up, the best from the lot, as a way to say "this might be acceptable if it existed among a number of non-promotional contributions". It helps deliver the message when the self-promo is somewhat relevant content and encourages positive engagement.

Comment: You did not answer if a custom flag would have been a better choice though. It can be said that this was the result of targeted flagging; perhaps this one post was not judged as objectively as it should have been as a result of it. One custom flag stating that that this is a potential spammer and linking to questions/answers as proof might have been the better approach, maybe?

Comment: @Gimby A custom flag would've provided more context for sure, but I would've handled it the same: helpful and no action. The question "how should I have flagged that post to get it deleted" has no answer with me, because I don't think that post had to be deleted. If that user's contributions had been handled by 1 mod today instead of 4 mods over several months, the outcome might have been different, but that's purely hypothetical.