# Our [diesel] vehicles are rusty

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [rust-diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-diesel) exists for some time and seems appropriate for the site.

However, I just saw [diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diesel) coming up in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74778680/10871900) which also seems to be about [rust-diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-diesel).

I think we should synonymize [diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diesel) into [rust-diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-diesel) as [diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diesel) is ambiguous (or alternatively block it as it could lead to difficulties [similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356485/rename-carbon-to-macos-carbon-and-synonym) [to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419541/too-much-carbon-is-bad-for-the-environment) [[carbon]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349864/disambiguate-the-carbon-tag)).

Please don't retag the questions before this is sorted out.

Comment: [diesel] is now a synonym of [rust-diesel]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the time it took you to post this question, you could've sorted out the whole *two questions* incorrectly tagged, as well as add usage guidance to [diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diesel) to advise people to not use it. I've done both - sorry not sorry, SO needs a lot more curation action and far less hand-wringing about what is the "right" thing to do.

As @E_net4 the comment flagger says, **if** this tag becomes a bigger problem, **then** we can consider blacklisting/burnination.

Answer (score 9):

> Please don't retag the questions before this is sorted out.

Well, it is already clear that [rust-diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-diesel) (322 questions) is the intended  tag for the [Diesel ORM](https://diesel.rs), whereas [diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diesel) (2 questions) was created by mistake. Retagging those questions to use [rust-diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-diesel) does not prevent us (much in the contrary) from blacklisting [diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diesel).

This does not really call for extra caution. Given the very low volume of questions with this problem, I would be inclined to edit these two questions right away, and only write a proposal to burninate or blacklist the tag if it keeps coming back.

Comment: I added the `Please don't retag the questions before this is sorted out.` in case we want to synonymize it instead of retagging